# Bash Script for find a Script in a path and launch that another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, zsh

Look , i have this script , its for find , a Script inside a "path" , and launch the another script called ".Iniciar"

```
#!/bin/sh

# La Funcion de este Script es encontrar el directorio
# Real donde se encuentra el programa

# La Version Original es de :
# 17 de Febrero del 2000 - Sam Lantinga, Loki Entertainment Software

# Esta Version Ha sido Traducida por
# Inukaze De Venezuela
# Sitio : http://inukaze.wordpress.com

Encontrar_Ruta()
{
    ruta_completa="`echo $1 | grep /`"
    if [ "$ruta_completa" = "" ]; then
        oIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=:
        for path in $PATH
        do if [ -x "$path/$1" ]; then
               if [ "$path" = "" ]; then
                   path="."
               fi
               ruta_completa="$path/$1"
               break
           fi
        done
        IFS="$oIFS"
    fi
    if [ "$ruta_completa" = "" ]; then
        ruta_completa="$1"
    fi

    if [ -L "$ruta_completa" ]; then
        ruta_completa=`ls -l "$ruta_completa" |sed -e 's/.* -> //' |sed -e 's/\*//'`
    fi
    dirname $ruta_completa
}

if [ "${RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE}" = "" ]; then
    RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE="`Encontrar_Ruta $0`"
fi

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:${RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

if [ -x "${RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE}/.Iniciar" ]
then
    cd "${RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE}/"
    exec "./.Iniciar" $*
fi
echo "No Puedo ejecutar este Software. Esta bien escrito el Script de Inicio?"
exit 1
```

Ok , the thing its this works with path without spaces , well , im trying to run from
path "/media/Compartido/Juegos/Emuladores & Roms/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"

for example when my terminal is in the folder "Desktop"

```
$ cd $HOME/Desktop
$ sh "/media/Compartido/Juegos/Emuladores & Roms/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"/Iniciar
No Puedo ejecutar este Software. Esta bien escrito el Script de Inicio?
```

I can't launch it

But if i copy the folder to "/media/Shared/Games/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"

```
[ inukaze | 23-09-2014 | 08:55 pm ]
[Desktop]$ sh "/media/Shared/Games/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"/Iniciar

Encontrado el Archivo de Configuracion para : Aladdin

DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file Aladdin.conf
MIXER:Got different values from SDL: freq 22050, blocksize 256
ALSA:Can't subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
Two or more joysticks reported, initializing with 2axis
Using joystick USB Gamepad  with 2 axes, 10 buttons and 0 hat(s)
Using joystick Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) with 6 axes, 11 buttons and 1 hat(s)
```

and trying with "zsh" from original location

```
[ inukaze | 23-09-2014 | 08:58 pm ]
[Desktop]$ zsh "/media/Compartido/Juegos/Emuladores & Roms/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"/Iniciar

Encontrado el Archivo de Configuracion para : Aladdin

DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file Aladdin.conf
MIXER:Got different values from SDL: freq 22050, blocksize 256
ALSA:Can't subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
Two or more joysticks reported, initializing with 2axis
Using joystick USB Gamepad  with 2 axes, 10 buttons and 0 hat(s)
Using joystick Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) with 6 axes, 11 buttons and 1 hat(s)
```

this works too , but i wanna ran from bash / sh

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If paths with spaces cause problems that **always** means you haven't used enough quoting.

Specifically you are using variables that can contain spaces without "quoting" them.

For example in the following line.

```
RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE="`Encontrar_Ruta $0`"
```

You don't quote `$0`. So when you run `sh "/media/Compartido/Juegos/Emuladores & Roms/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin"/Iniciar` despite quoting the path as the argument there when you use that path (as `$0`) in the line above what the shell sees is:

```
RUTA_DEL_SOFTWARE="`Encontrar_Ruta '/media/Compartido/Juegos/Emuladores' '&' 'Roms/MS-D.O.S/Aladdin/Iniciar'`"
```

which then doesn't set `$1` correctly in your function.

So to sum up: [Use more quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html).

Comment: I solve it , its for "PATH" varible inside in the maked .desktop file . i erase that line , and now its working